# App crashs on Debug scheme but works good on Beta scheme - multiple targets

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have an app with 3 schemes : Debug, Beta and Release.

I have a TableView with multiple different table cell views, 3 of them are CollectionViews.

When building the Beta Scheme, the app works as expected s without any issues, rolling back to a different scheme (Debug) fails with this error :

> thread 1: Assertion failed: This is a feature to warn you that there
>   is already a delegate (or data source) set somewhere previously. The
>   action you are trying to perform will clear that delegate (data
>   source) and that means that some of your features that depend on that
>   delegate (data source) being set will likely stop working. If you are
>   ok with this, try to set delegate (data source) to `nil` in front of
>   this operation.  This is the source object value:

The error point to this part:

```
func bindViewModel() {
       viewModel.transform().asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])
           .drive(self.collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, cellType: ProductImageItemCell.self)) { collectionView, viewModel, cell in
               cell.bind(to: viewModel)
           }.disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)

   }
```

What is the issue behind this? Am I have a bad multiple target configuration done wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `bindViewModel()` function creates and connects a dataSource to your collection view. However, you apparently already have a datasource connected. Whatever functionality that first data source is supposed to provide is going to be lost. Maybe that first datasource was a mistake and isn't needed. In that case, remove it.

Comment: I see, Is there any way to debug and figure out where the first datasource was set?

Comment: If you are using, or deriving from, a UICollectionViewController then it is set in the loadView method, just set it to nil before you call `bindViewModel()`. Otherwise, you likely have it set in the storyboard, just break the link there. It is also possible that you have called `collectionView.dataSource = self` (or something else,) just remove it.